# Mensa IQ test question: complete the logical sequence

Tags: explanation, sequence

I tried taking the Mensa practice test. One of the question involved completing a series of figures with the most logical option. This is the base sequence:

[image: BaseSquence]

And we have to choose the additional figure from these four options:

[image: Four Options]

I chose correctly, but admittedly did it mostly intuitively. I'd like to understand why the correct answer is:

> Option 2: The three small black triangles

The only reasoning I could come up with seems dubious at best:

> Alternance of shapes and lines; avoiding repeating figures; first two figures don't have angles, third does, so fourth should too.

Is there an obvious explanation that I'm missing here?

Reference to the full test (requires to provide an email address for results): http://mbe.webfactional.com/members/cgi-bin/preTest/preTest_v3.cgi?lang=fr

Comment: Looks to me like it's just a bad question.

Comment: I've VTC as "primarily opinion-based" because 3 random pictures does not make a pattern : answers will be based more on opinion than logic

Comment: Wow, that's a *horrible* question.

Comment: @Lordofdark I agree that the IQ-test question itself is worthy of closure, but the question here is actually a good one:  "Please explain to me why this puzzle's solution is what it is."  It's completely within the scope of this site.  (There's even a tag for it: [tag:explanation].)

Comment: @Lordofdark Surely if this is can be shown to be only a matter of opinion, that itself is the answer to the question? "There can't be any objective answer or explanation to this because three items isn't enough to establish a pattern, because [cite relevant principle of puzzling]".

Comment: This isn't a matter of opinion.  The triangles are the most logical.  Each of the other 3 options are mirror images of the 3 figures in the sequence.

Comment: Lol............

Comment: OP can you please provide the link or reference to the original puzzle

Comment: Seems like that question is to test if you were able to find the new one since the three others was already there. Personnaly i was on the 2nd one and was hammering myself like "is this that simple ?". Does this test is measured accordingly to the time it take you ? That would just be to mesure how fast you were instead of just find the right answer

Comment: Here is the context of this question: https://imgur.com/a/aEfIw